# What does this JQuery code mean and when will it get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and I see a piece of code in a web page:

```
$(function() {
     //do something...
});
```

I don't understand the syntax here. 
Does it define a function? 
When will it get called?
Can I re-use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the short version of jQuerys DOM ready handler. The code inside the function will be called on page load, when the `DOMReady` event has fired.

It is equivalent to the following which is a little more verbose, but clearer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: oh, i see. I know $(document).ready, but did not know it has a short version. :)..  thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

The function will be called once the Document Object Model (DOM) is ready (Page Load).

It is shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // Commands here
});
```

You would put all of your functions/scripts inside it that you want to load once the page loads.

Comment: Are you reeeeeeeeeeeeeeady, are you reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeady for DOM? Yes I am oooooooooooo yes I am

Comment: Wow. I didn't know Elton John knew jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah Rocketman was originally entitled *document* after his love of HTML also, chorus went DOCUMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEENNNNNNNNNNT. Apparently he has a StackOverflow account, but so far I've only been able to locate Cliff Richard and Donny Osmond on here thus far. +1 to you both :)

Comment: I think you've ruined the DOMReady handler for me now. EVERY time I write it from now on I'm going to think of that damn song. And I thank you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan haha I suppose there are *far worse* songs that could be associated :)

Answer (score 1):

**It's a wrapper for the [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event which fires when the DOM has loaded.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

*Which is an event that fires when the DOM has loaded (but excluding images).*

**An alternative is**

```
$(window).load(function() {

});
```

*Which fires when everything has loaded (including images)*

Answer (score 1):

That is the main thing that you need to use to make jQuery work. That function will happen *after the document has fully loaded (excluding images)*. Anything inside that, or this (the code you pasted is shorthand for the following):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // anything inside this will happen only after the document has fully loaded
});
```

If you just put the code in the script tags, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('div').css('background-color','green'); // sets all <div> CSS background to green
</script>
```

It would only work on divs before these tags (and if you put it in the `<head>`, then it wouldn't work at all). If you put it in `$(function() { });` or `$(document).ready(function() { });` (whatever you prefer, I prefer the second option) then it will work on all `div` elements that are present in the DOM after it has fully loaded (just the actual HTML, not after images have loaded).

And yes, you can use this as many times as you want on your page.

More info here: [Tutorials: Introducing $(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)